# Log ApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent() calls

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I've got an Spring Boot 2.2 Application which publishes and consumes spring application events in different packages. Now I want to log every time an event has been published by `ApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent()`.

One solution could be to write my own event publisher like:

```java
public class LoggableApplicationEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisher {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    private final Logger logger;

    public ApplicationEventLogger(ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher, Logger logger) {

        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        this.logger = logger;
    }


    @Override
    public void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

        eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
        logger.info("--> Emitting {}", event);
    }
}
```

Another solution could be to use aspect oriented programming and write an Aspect which is triggered everytime `publishEvent()` has been triggered:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class EventPublishAspect {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher.*(..))")
    public void logPublishEvent() {
    }


    @After("logPublishEvent()")
    public void log(JoinPoint point) {

        Object[] lArgs = point.getArgs();
        LOG.info("Triggered", lArgs[0]);
    }
}
```

I've set up all correctly (dependencies aswell) and this example is working for other pointcuts (like for a call of specific method of my services).

However, this aspect is not working with the declared pointcut for the `ApplicationEventPublisher`-Interface. Do you know why not? It seems like spring boot injects `AbstractApplicationContext` on runtime, which is actually implementing this interface.

Comment: Because the `ApplicationEventPublisher` **is** the `ApplicationContext` it isn't a Spring Managed bean but the container itself. As AOP only applies to spring managed beans it simply won't work (it won't proxy the container it is running in). So unless you resort to compile time weaving this won't work.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. So if I want to achieve my goal at runtime, do I need to list every method of my different services (which are publishing an event) in my pointcut?
Or is there another solution (except compile time weaving).

Comment: Load-time weaving is also an option. You need to run your container with `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` and use an `aop.xml` file. But you definitely need to use AspectJ, not Spring AOP, as was said before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that does not require aspects (and has faster startup time?)

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    DelegatingApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        new DelegatingApplicationEventPublisher(applicationContext)
    }
```

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DelegatingApplicationEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisher {

    private final ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        logEvent(event);
        context.publishEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void publishEvent(Object event) {
        logEvent(event);
        context.publishEvent(event);
    }

    private void logEvent(Object event) {
        if (event instanceof PayloadApplicationEvent payloadApplicationEvent) {
            log.debug(markers("eventName", payloadApplicationEvent.getPayload().getClass(), "event", payloadApplicationEvent.getPayload()), "publishing...");
        } else {
            log.debug(markers("eventName", event.getClass(), "event", event), "publishing ...");
        }
    }

}
```